# How to get the content of XML nodes that have little differences? (C#)

Tags: c#, xml

I want to parse different XML that all of them have the same content but with this differences:

Some of the XML are like:

```
<ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIDtT[...]lLgXlaoNwM=</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data>
```

Others are:

```
<dsig:X509Data><dsig:X509Certificate>MIIDtT[...]lLgXlaoNwM=</dsig:X509Certificate></dsig:X509Data>
```

I want to get the content of the "X509Certificate" node to save it in a file.

For other parts of the XML that are always the same, I was using:

```
doc.GetElementsByTagName("CountryName");
```

But I cant do the same here.

What should I do?

Comment: If your documents use different prefixes for the same namespace, you should be able to handle this using a [XmlNamespaceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/managing-namespaces-in-an-xml-document).

Comment: Or better, use LINQ to XML which has simpler support for namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and query it with LINQ.

```
var certificates = from doc in xDoc.Root.documents()
         from attr in doc.Attributes()
         where attr.Name.ToString().Contains("X509Certificate")
         select attr;
```

You can now loop through `certificates` and read in the values